# R append data frames in a nested for loop

Tags: r, loops, nested, append

I am trying to run some calculations within a nested for loop and record each result in a dataframe.  I want the loops to run through each possible combination of variables, and append a row to a dataframe.  This is what I have tried so far, it gets me part way there but not all iterations get recorded.  Any ideas how to do this?

```
set.seed(7)
library(dplyr)

list_pts <- list(rnorm(5), rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
list_PET <- list(rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
list_GWpts <- list(rnorm(5), rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
list_Rain <- list(rnorm(5), rnorm(5), rnorm(5))

datalist1 <- list()
datalist2 <- list()
datalist3 <- list()
datalist4 <- list()


for (z in 1:3) {  # loop for varying pts
  
  pts <- list_pts[[z]]
  pts_used <- z
  
  for (f in 1:2){  # loop for varying PET
    PET <- list_PET[[f]]
    PET_used <- f
    
    for (y in 1:3) {  # loop for varying GW pts
      
      GWpts <- list_GWpts[[y]]
      GWpts_used <- y
      
      for (u in 1:3) {   # loop for varying rain dataset
        
        RAIN <- list_Rain[[u]] # 
        rain_used <- u
        
        
        #####  Do some calculations using input variables in lists (not shown)
        catchment <- c('Okaro','Rotomahana','Tarawera')
        area <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
        calc <- c(25245, 434, 231)
        output <- data.frame(catchment, area, calc)
        ########
        
        output$varA <- pts_used
        output$varB <- PET_used
        output$varC <- GWpts_used
        output$varD <- rain_used
        
        datalist1[[u]] <- output
      }
      
      big_data1 <- dplyr::bind_rows(datalist1)
      datalist2[[y]] <- output
      
    }
    big_data2 <- dplyr::bind_rows(datalist2)
    datalist3[[f]] <- output
  }
  big_data3 <- dplyr::bind_rows(datalist3)
  datalist4[[z]] <- output
}
big_data4 <- dplyr::bind_rows(datalist4)

big_data_all <- dplyr::bind_rows(datalist1, datalist2, datalist3, datalist4)
```

This is what I want my output to look like (only shows the head of the output):

| catchment | area | calc | varA | varB | varC | varD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Okaro | 21000 | 25245 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Rotomahana | 23400 | 434 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Tarawera | 26800 | 231 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Okaro | 21000 | 25245 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Rotomahana | 23400 | 434 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Tarawera | 26800 | 231 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Okaro | 21000 | 25245 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Rotomahana | 23400 | 434 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Tarawera | 26800 | 231 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Okaro | 21000 | 25245 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Rotomahana | 23400 | 434 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Tarawera | 26800 | 231 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Okaro | 21000 | 25245 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Rotomahana | 23400 | 434 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Tarawera | 26800 | 231 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Okaro | 21000 | 25245 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Rotomahana | 23400 | 434 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Tarawera | 26800 | 231 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Okaro | 21000 | 25245 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Rotomahana | 23400 | 434 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Tarawera | 26800 | 231 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: Hello Nicki, did you try using the expand.grid() function ? If you give as argument a list it will give you a dataframe with all combinations you are looking for. You could therefore use the output of the expand.grid() function to make a simple loop (throug the number of rows of this output) and to pick the parameters stored at the i-th row of it. Have you tried this option yet?

Comment: Can you use `set.seed` to generate random data and show expected output for it so that it is clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ronak Shah - I have edited my original post.  The random numbers actually don't make a diffference, they are just used in my example to put something in the list elements.  However, I have added a table at the bottom showing my desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicki,

Here is a solution that I hope will answer your question. You can use the expand.grid() function implemented in R base. This will allow you to have in output a table containing all the possible combinations that interest you. From this, you can loop over the number of possible combinations and you are sure not to miss any. The dummy example below allows you to sum up all your parameters for each possible combination.

```
my_list <- list(A=c(1,2,3),B=c(4,5))
output <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(my_list))
output$result <- NA #new variable to store your calculus
```

The output table has for number of rows the number of possible combinations. Then you just have to go through each line in a loop and make the calculations you like by storing them in this same table for example.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(output)){
  output$result[i] <- sum(output[i,1:2])
}
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: That would work to achieve what I am trying to do - thank you.